# Filter mercurial status by branch name

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to get an hg status list for a range of revisions, and also filter the list for a given branch name.
e.g. The issue with this command is that it includes changes from multiple branches, and I'm only interested in a particular branch:

```
hg status --rev 150:175
```

Is there a way to add an additional filter by branch for this list with hg or a mainstream hg tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets):

`hg status --rev "150:175 and branch(<BRANCH_NAME>)`"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use revsets (`hg help revsets`) to do this. There are a large number of options for selecting revisions, but I think that what you want would be something along these lines:

```
hg status --rev "150:175 and branch(mybranch)"
```

Revsets can be tricky at times, but they are very powerful, and so well worth reading about them in `hg help`.